# Changing date format in access table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a field in which users should enter either a date for an order or specify if that order was 'CANCELLED'. I therefore made the field of type text. In order to keep the date format consistent in the database, I would like that field to store the date entered in Medium Date. I don't think I can use the Format function to fix this. I am using VBA for this Access application.
Should I rather use a checkbox/check type field for CANCELLED value and make the 'Order_Date' field of type date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter, don't mix types in a field. Have nullable `Order_Date` field a date and a `boolean` field for whether the order was cancelled.